# iMS-20 for Logic Pro

Tags: logic-pro

Is there an iMS-20 equivalent for Logic (apart from "es m")?

I'm mainly interested in two things: (1) the unique sound, (2) overlapping recording for MIDI, so that I would be able to leave a loop on, and try getting the best tune out of 20 or so tries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Korg [publishes a plugin](http://www.korg.com/Product.aspx?pd=588) that emulates the MS-20 synthesizer.  This is the same synthesizer that is emulated by the iMS-20 iPad app, so you should be able to get the sound you're looking for.

It's available in AU and VST format so it should work with Logic, and I presume you can use MIDI with it like most any other virtual instrument, so you should be able to do whatever kind of MIDI looping and overdubbing that you want.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Bob! Guess why I haven't rated your question yet. Yup. Haven't been able to stop playing, hehe. Best 50 bucks I've spent in a while.